# Xcode's shared workgroup 'Unreachable' after Snow Leopard/Xcode upgrade

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard

After upgrading to OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and iPhone SDK 3.1 (with Xcode 3.2), Xcode's *shared workgroup builds* (distributed) can't seem to find or access other computers in our office.

Distributed builds worked perfectly in OS X 10.5 with iPhone SDK 3.0.

All the computers that have upgraded are now listed with a status of *Unreachable*. Even my own computer, *artanis*, is listed as Unreachable!

I've already tried all of the suggestions listed in [Troubleshooting Distributed Network Builds](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2007/oct/msg00403.html). And none of us have the OS X firewall enabled.

Any suggestions?

Here's a screenshot:
[Xcode Preferences Screenshot http://img170.imageshack.us/img170/3972/screenshot20090917at104.png](http://img170.imageshack.us/img170/3972/screenshot20090917at104.png)

Comment: Did you allready reinstall the snowleopard version of XCode ?

Comment: I thought iPhone SDK 3.1 (final, not the beta version) includes Xcode 3.2 (the Snow Leopard version). All we did was uninstall iPhone SDK 3.0, install Snow Leopard, install iPhone SDK 3.1 (for Snow Leopard).

Comment: I have exactly the same issue: updated 10.6 (10.6.1), xcode 3.2 from original DVD. Firewall disabled. No solution yet!

Comment: Same problem here. Will be watching this thread for a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems to be to run Xcode in "32-bit" mode - you set this in the "Get Info" dialog in the Finder.

Answer (score 1):

You must re-install Xcode using the version on the Snow Leopard DVD. The iPhone SDK must be re-installed afterwards.

Edit: I just noticed that Apple started distributing Xcode 3.2 with the iPhone 3.1 SDK. I would recommend you to attempt a full uninstall of the developer tools, as described in the SDK release notes (see developer.apple.com), and then to re-install it. You should also check that each computer have a unique name set in system preferences>>sharing. As a last resort, I'd check that Snow Leopard was booted in 32-bit mode (it does by default), and (just for the test) try to boot Snow Leopard in 64-bit mode (hold the 6 and 4 keys while booting).

Edit 2: Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363137/how-well-does-xgrid-work-with-xcode-for-parallel-compiling), it seems related. Maybe you should try to enable Xgrid in sharing preferences?

Comment: Some MacBooks cannot boot in x64 mode (disabled by Apple). Also Xgrid enablement does not solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem installing it now it works since it needed for the xcode and ipphone sdk the firewall disabled to install, I think that fix my problem where it did not want to install the files strange bug I guess, with firewall on , the installer fails to install, and I am still in 64bit mode