# iPhone team dev, do we all need the same OS?

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, ipod-touch, osx-leopard

I´m just starting iPhone development with a small team of (really young and naive) colleagues, we all are fairly new to OS X, my question is:

If we are planning to develop for every iPod Touch/iPhone out there (not the iPad, I read that thing requires Snow Leopard), what problems will we encounter when sharing code (and making commits) if we all have a combination of Leopard and Snow Leopard systems?

Comment: You need the same version of Xcode, and the same version of the iPhone SDK. This may or may not require Snow Leopard. That being said, if it ever causes a problem, Snow Leopard's 40 bucks.

Comment: actually Snow Leopard is $29 US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be OK as long as you're not using the iPhone SDK version 3.2, which requires Snow Leopard, as you already know. You'll be using Xcode 3.1.4 on Leopard and Xcode 3.2.1 on Snow Leopard. One caveat: ensure that you save your project as compatible with Xcode 3.1 (which is the default) and don't change its compatibility level to 3.2 unless everyone is on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score -4):

Xcode's distributed build system ([when it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439745/xcodes-shared-workgroup-unreachable-after-snow-leopard-xcode-upgrade)) will only distribute to the same OS (version). So if you really use distributed builds, you'd see a gain from all being on the same OS.

Comment: A distributed build is an intensive build where several machines are leveraged to speed up a single build. This answer is not even remotely relevant for some guys starting out as iPhone developers. These guys should be checking out the project from an SVN repository (works quite well in XCode). The real answer is "you'll be fine", you can do current iPhone dev on Leopard or Snow Leopard. However, since Snow Leopard is only 30 bucks and offers a far superior version of XCode, I recommend that you all use that. It'll make your lives easier.

Comment: :3 thanks for the update! seems like we'll be upgrading and stop being stingy with our wallets.